# React: How do I send a prop to a click function in ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning React and am having trouble sending props to a click function. I'm trying to create a simple ES6 counter component that increments when a button is clicked.

My click function is simply:

```
click() {
   this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + value
    })
}
```

I have set defaultProps as such:

```
Counter.defaultProps = { valueOne: 1 }
```

And have created my button, within the render function:

```
<Button className="btn" clickHandler={this.click} text="Click me" value={this.props.valueOne}/>
```

But I can't figure out who to get the button to 'send' the click function the value on click. I just get the message `value is not defined`.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction here?

Any help is appreciated.

My full code is:

```
       class Counter extends React.Component {

            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = { count: 0 };
                this.click = this.click.bind(this);
            }

            click() {
                this.setState({
                    count: this.state.count + value
                })
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div className="container">
                      <h1>Count {this.state.count}</h1>
                        <Button className="btn blue-btn" clickHandler={this.click} text="Click me" value={this.props.valueOne}/>
                    </div>
                )
            }

        }

        Counter.defaultProps = { valueOne: 1 } //Defaults

        const Button = (props) => {
            return (
                <button className={props.className} onClick={props.clickHandler} value={props.value}>{props.text}</button>
            )
        }

        ReactDOM.render(
            <Counter valueOne={1} valueTwo={10} valueThree={100} />, 
            document.getElementById('app')
        );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in `event.target.value`, just change the handler to:

```
click(event) {
    this.setState({
        count: this.state.count + event.target.value
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  class Counter extends React.Component {

            constructor(props) {
                super(props);
                this.state = { count: 0,
                               valueOne: 1
                             };
                this.click = this.click.bind(this);
            }

            click(event) {
                this.setState({
                    count: this.state.count + event.target.value
                })
            }

            render() {
                return (
                    <div className="container">
                      <h1>Count {this.state.count}</h1>
                        <Button className="btn blue-btn" clickHandler={this.click} text="Click me" value={this.state.valueOne}/>
                    </div>
                )
            }

        }
```

Is this in essence what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the value with `event.target.value`.
But I notice there is a possible bug in your code, since `this.setState` could be executed asynchronously (as explained [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous)). You better use the second version of setState that accept a callback, and not just an object. Like this:

```
    click(event) {
      this.setState((prevState) => {
         return {
            count: prevState.count + event.target.value
         }
      })
    }
```